# ¿Cómo evitar el desbordamiento de un enlace que se visualiza junto a un texto obtenido de una base de datos?

Tags: css

En mi proyecto genero  tarjetas de noticias de forma dinámica, la cual contiene varios elementos, dos de ellos son un `<span>` que contiene texto(truncado con una función `truncar()`) obtenido de mi base de datos y al lado un enlace`<a>` "Leer mas", este ultimo en ocasiones(depende de las dimensiones) se desborda del contenedor de la tarjeta, he probado varias modificaciones pero no logro dar con una solución, de momento lo he dejado al enlace con un `display: block;` pero mi idea es que quede pegado al texto antes nombrado, cabe aclarar que ya he probado con `display: inline-block;` , con `display: inline;` y otras combinaciones.
Una muestra de como se desborda.
Añado parte de la función donde se imprime las tarjetas dinámicas y el CSS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
/*-----------------------------TARJETA-------------------------------*/
.tarjeta{
  position: relative;
  border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.062) solid 1px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px grey;
  transition: box-shadow 0.7s,margin-left 0.5s;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%; 

}
.tarjeta:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px rgba(118, 0, 252);
}
.titulo_tar{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-decoration: none; 
}
.titulo_tar:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
.img_tar{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 180px;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}
.seccion_tar{
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 2px 10px 3px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:135px;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Actividades{
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 150);
}
.Artículos{
  background-color:rgb(118, 0, 252);
}
.Informes{
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.Medios{
  background-color: green; 
}
.fecha_tar{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}
.texto_tar{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  top: 225px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.link_tar{
  text-decoration: none;
  position:absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
      {
          echo "<div class='tarjeta'>";  
            echo "<a class='titulo_tar' href='#'>$fila[0]</a>";
            echo "<img class='img_tar' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode( $fila[4] )."' alt='noticia'>";
            echo "<span class='seccion_tar $fila[1]'>$fila[1]<span class='fecha_tar'>$fila[2]</span></span>";
            echo "<span class='texto_tar'>".truncar($fila[3],230)."<a class='link_tar' href='#'>Leer más.</a></span>";
          echo "</div>";
      }
```